# What is an owner drawn listbox?

Tags: definition, ownerdrawn

Please excuse my ignorance, but I have come across this term "owner drawn" listbox.  Can someone experienced with this explain what exactly that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Buttons, menus, static text controls,
>   list boxes, and combo boxes can be
>   created with an owner-drawn style
>   flag. When a control has the
>   owner-drawn style, the system handles
>   the user's interaction with the
>   control as usual, performing such
>   tasks as detecting when a user has
>   chosen a button and notifying the
>   button's owner of the event. However,
>   because the control is owner-drawn,
>   the parent window of the control is
>   responsible for the visual appearance
>   of the control. The parent window
>   receives a message whenever the
>   control must be drawn.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775501%28VS.85%29.aspx) msdn article.